# Can I return a column with it's value as two columns?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to have my columns returned as values, along with the answer to that row based on an ID. I have a table with ~80 ish columns, and I need to return the name of that column along with it's value, i.e.
The point is, I need to do this dynamically as I need it for multiple tables.

Current situation

```
RowID|Col a | col b | col c | col d
----------------------------
1    |val a | val b | val c | val d|


Output situation:

Return: 
Column Name | Value | 
col a       | val a |
col b       | val b |
col c       | val c |
col d       | val d |
Where RowID = 1
```

I've tried pulling the information from information_schema.columns and manipulating that, but I've not been able to get to the solution myself..

Comment: You're asking how to [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) a wide table and convert columns into rows?

Comment: Basically. I want to just have two columns; the column name and it's value.

Comment: That's an UNPIVOT operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this. Since you have many columns so you must use dynamic sql, and `unpivot` is use to convert your column into rows. For more info about `unpivot` you may find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

```
----- yourtable and Id_col name will be pass dynamically to reuse this query for multiple columns.
DECLARE @COL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COL = ( SELECT 
              STUFF( (SELECT ',[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                -----  here ID_Col will be replaced by set of columns need to excluded from your final output table.
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME<>'ID_COL' FOR XML PATH('')   
                   ),1,1,'')  )

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT ID_COL, Col, Val  
FROM   
   (SELECT ID_COL, ' + @COL + ' FROM YOURTABLE ) D
UNPIVOT  
   (Val FOR Col IN (' + @COL + ' )  
) AS unpvt'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) as follows:

```
SELECT RowId, Col, Val  
FROM   
   (SELECT RowID, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD  
   FROM tbl) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Val FOR Col IN   
      (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD )  
)AS unpvt
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/619d8/2/0

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use the `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES()`. You may also use `UNPIVOT()` or `UNION ALL`

```
select  RowID, [Column Name], [Value]
from    yourtable
        cross apply
        (
            values 
            ('Col a', [Col a]),
            ('Col b', [Col b]),
            ('Col c', [Col c]),
            ('Col d', [Col d])
        ) v ([Column Name], [Value])
```